# Image of ring homomorphism is a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\phi : R\to  S $ be a ring homomorphism.

> Definition:
>
> $Im\left ( \phi \right )=\left ( R \right )\phi=\left \{ \left ( a \right )\phi \mid a \in R \right \}$

Prove that $Im\left ( \phi  \right )$is a subring of S

By the subring test, we need to show that the $Im\left ( \phi  \right )$ is closed under multiplication and subtraction.

Suppose $\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi,\left ( a_{2} \right )\phi \in Im\left ( \phi \right )$.
Thus, $s_{1}=\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi$ and $s_{2}=\left ( a_{2} \right )\phi \in Im\left ( \phi \right )$

$\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi$ + (-$\left ( a_{2} \right ))\phi=  s_{1}-s_{2}$ but S is a ring so $s_{1}-s_{2} \in$ S

Is this correct?

Comment: Your title does not make sense: what you mean is «The *image* of a ring homomorphism is a subring».

Comment: Why is $\phi$ written to the right of the argument?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A little changes needed.`
Suppose $\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi,\left ( a_{2} \right )\phi \in Im\left ( \phi \right )$.
Thus, $s_{1}:=\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi$ and $s_{2}:=\left ( a_{2} \right )\phi $.

Now $\left ( a_{1} \right )\phi + (-\left ( a_{2} \right ))\phi= s_1-s_2$ but S is a ring so $s_{1}-s_{2} \in S,$ Hence $s_1-s_2\in Im \phi.$

One also should check in similar way  the multiplication.