# Ring homomorphism and Subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm linking this theorem below:

[Image of ring homomorphism is a subring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792499/image-of-ring-homomorphism-is-a-subring)

I'm new to the concept of Ring Theory so my question is, how do I prove/disprove that the converse of the theorem is true? As far as I've read, it's true for inclusion maps. But can it be true for other types of maps?

Comment: I don't know it would help or not, but you can check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4448425/is-every-ring-a-homomorphic-image-of-some-abelian-groups-endomorphism-ring